# How to get a range of values of 2 numbers with Quadratic easing function?

Tags: javascript, easing, quadratic

I saw [this article](https://css-tricks.com/ease-y-breezy-a-primer-on-easing-functions/) talking about the easing functions. And there is a part which talking about **Quadratic ease functions** and there has a chart showing the range of numbers between 0 and 1 using this code:

```js
const quad_easing = (t) => t * t;

let easing_vals = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 1; i += 0.1) {
  easing_vals.push(quad_easing(i));
}

console.log(easing_vals)
```

What if I want to find the range of numbers between **5 and 90** but I just want **10 steps** of it? This means the 10 numbers will be **[5, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, 90]** and is generated using **Quadratic easing functions**.

Answer (score 0):

your function would provide a result for a b c d... etc

such as `function(i, t){ return i % t; }`

you would pass that function as the operand and it would execute for i and t which are the input and time respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiplying the results of your existing function should give you the result you are after:

```js
function doit(min, max, steps) {
    const quad_easing = (t) => t * t;
    const diff = max - min;
    let easing_vals = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < steps; i += 1) {
    easing_vals.push(quad_easing(i / (steps - 1)) * diff + min);
    }
    return easing_vals;
}
console.log(doit(5, 90, 10));
```

Comment: It would benefit from a ,toFixed(2): `easing_vals.push(+(quad_easing(i) * diff + min).toFixed(2))`

Comment: Or `Math.round` but the depends on the needs of the OP.

Comment: Hmm...the result give 11 steps instead of 10 steps that is set...do I need to minus 1?